# Transfer files over SSH, then appended to another file

Tags: ssh, scp

I'm trying to automate a script that copies a file from my local server to a remote server on the command line. I've done the research on scp and know how to copy the file to the remote server, but then I want to append that file to another.

This is my code:

```
scp ~/file.txt user@host:
ssh user@host cat file.txt >> other_file.txt
```

When I enter everything into the command line manually as such, everything works fine:

```
scp ~/file.txt user@host:
ssh user@host
cat file.txt >> other_file.txt
```

But when I run the script, only the file is copied, not appended to the end of other_file.txt. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line of your code should be

```
ssh user@host "cat file.txt >> other_file.txt"
```

Three important points:

1. You don't want your *local* shell to interpret `>>` in any way (which it does if it's unquoted)
2. There *is* a remote shell which will interpret `>>` in the command correctly.
3. Final arguments to `ssh` are "joined" to form a command, not carried into an `argv` array as they are. It may be convenient but it also may lead to confusion or bugs: `ssh cat "$MYFILE"` and `ssh "cat '$MYFILE'"` both *work* in a common use case, but they *both* break for *different* values of `$MYFILE`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the command to be run on the remote host in quotes. Otherwise, the redirection is being done locally rather than remotely. Try this instead:

```
scp ~/file.txt user@host:
ssh user@host 'cat file.txt >> other_file.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $ cat file.txt| ssh hostname 'cat >> other_file.txt'
```